# Struts2 xml validation form fields not highlighting

Tags: java, struts2

I am able to validate form fields using XML validation and able to display error messages on screen. But form fields like text fields, radio buttons, check boxes are not highlighting in red after validation error messages throws on screen. Should I use CSS to show up fields turn to red...?

Comment: What `theme` are you using for the `form` of those non-highlighting fields?

Comment: I am using theme simple

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

Comment: @user1380678: If you want to highlight form elements which fails validation see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using `theme="simple"` on a form you lose the default `fielderror`, so you need to create one manually:

```
<s:fielderror>
    <s:param>nameOfTheFormField1</s:param>
    <s:param>nameOfTheFormField2</s:param>
    <!-- More -->
</s:fielderror>
```

You can check the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/fielderror.html) for configure it the way you want.

And [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/using-field-validators.html) you have a complete example.

Comment: Edited links because 2.1 documentation version has problems with CSS. +1 btw

Comment: It is seems OP knows how to show field error messages. Question is about highlighting them.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 form tags (like `<s:textfield>`, `<s:radio>`, etc.) have `cssErrorStyle` and `cssErrorClass` attributes for that.

```
<s:textfield key="fieldName" cssErrorStyle="background-color: red;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the tag `<s:head />` in your JSP page(which you are validating) it will work fine for you. The errors will be highlighted with red and bold.